# How to do asyncronous file transfers over sftp?

Tags: python, asynchronous, parallel-processing, sftp, paramiko

The problem I'm trying to solve is the following:
I have a desktop computer with large amounts of data (~5 TB), that I want to analyze. The data consist of 500k files, and each file can be analyzed individually.
For the analysis I have a series of servers at the university available, however, the server does not have space for all this data, nor does it have space to store the output of the analysis.

So my idea is to copy the data over to the server in segments, run the analysis, transfer the results back to the desktop, delete both input and output data on the server, and repeat.

For the file transfer I installed paramiko yesterday and it seems to work great:

```
remote_get = 'test'
local_deliver = './test'

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_path):
    for fname in files:
        full_fname = os.path.join(root, fname)
        full_remote = os.path.join(remote_path, fname)
        sftp.put(full_fname, full_remote)
sftp.close()
ssh.close()
```

However my only problem is that the amount of data I will need to transfer will likely take days to get back and forth, and hence I would love to start the data transfer asynchronously if possible, such that I can do analysis on the current dataset while transferring the next dataset to be analyzed.

But I don't have any clue how to do such a thing, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Do you mean you want to manually kick off the job and have multiple threads/processes moving data? Or do you want the program always running and have it copy files over when new ones arrive on the desktop?

Comment: I want to manually kick it off. The amount of input data remains the same.

Comment: It's not clear to me how asynchronous transfer helps you achieve your goal. What can you do with multiple processes sharing the same thread and being scheduled based on when FDs are ready for read/write that you couldn't do with a different thread for each file you want to concurrently copy? (Whereas if you don't want to copy more than one file at the time, "what does asynchrony give you?" becomes even less clear).

Comment: different threads for each file can probably also do the job, the point is just that I don't want my server to be idle while I'm transferring data to and from the server.

Comment: Gotcha. Honestly, that being the case, I'd consider breaking the work down into separate processes. If you have a `transfer-and-process` script that, given a filename, first copies the file to the remote server and then processes it there, something as simple as `find . -type f -print0 | xargs -n 1 -P 5 ./transfer-and-process` could suffice. That's not _ideal_ for a few reasons, but it's a place to start thinking about the problem; a better approach, if your processing is faster than your transfer speed, is just to have a script on the remote side that watches for new files in a directory...

Comment: ...and processes them as soon as they show up; have your transfer code first write to a temporary location and rename into the directory that consists of the ready queue when done, and there you are.

Comment: ...if processing is slower than transferring, by contrast, you'd need backpressure to make sure you don't run out of hard drive space on the remote server, so the transfer code would need to pause when the set of transferred-but-unprocessed files gets too large.

Comment: Alternately, you could open a network share from the local machine that the servers can mount (unix style NFS or windows style CIFS mounts). Assuming the servers only scan and write the data once, there is no more overhead than if you copied. If you want to prestage the data on the server, it can copy from the share when needed.

Answer (score 2):

This solution uses `multiprocessing.Pool` to create a task pool of separate processes. Each time you call `apply_async`, you pass a function pointer and a list of args. In this case, the function to perform is `copy_file` and the arg is the filename:

```
import os
import paramiko

from multiprocessing import Pool

remote_get = 'test'
local_deliver = './test'

pool = Pool(processes=4)  # Experiment with this number based on your # CPUs
def copy_file(filename):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.load_host_keys(os.path.expanduser(os.path.join("~", ".ssh", "known_hosts")))
    ssh.connect(server, username=username, password=password)
    sftp = ssh.open_sftp()

    full_fname = os.path.join(root, fname)
    full_remote = os.path.join(remote_path, fname)
    sftp.put(full_fname, full_remote)
    sftp.close()
    ssh.close()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk(local_deliver):
    for fname in files:
        pool.apply_async(copy_file, [fname])
```

There were a few variables from your original which weren't accounted for, so I used my best guess. The ssh and sftp client creation needs to be moved inside `copy_file` since you can't save it and share it between processes unless it's serializable.

The `processes` arg on `multiprocessing.Pool` can be tweaked based on number of CPUs, but keep in mind that you'll be battling against multiple bottlenecks here: 1. CPU, 2. NIC bandwidth limit, 3. Disk I/O limits.

Here's some more multiprocessing documentation: https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#using-a-pool-of-workers

EDIT: I just remembered as well that paramiko's SFTP vs shelling out SFTP commands was significantly slower. It may be worth writing out batch files and executing them with `subprocess.call` to get even better performance.

Comment: This is a really good answer, and while I haven't implemented it yet, I think this will solve my problem, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, glad to help. I just thought of one more option to explore: check out `rsync`. It may not suit your needs completely, but it's worth checking out.

Comment: I'd also suggest lftp; rsync requires another copy of rsync at the other end, and a generic ssh transport to run it over; lftp can run over sftp even when shell access is turned off, and works even on systems where one doesn't have a shell on the destination. (The cost of that is that one doesn't get differential transfers -- resuming interrupted transfers is append-only -- but it sounds like the OP doesn't have files on the destination that would benefit from that anyhow).